# Custom response and parameters for baucis swagger docs

Tags: baucis

I see that it is relatively easy to add docs to swagger UI for custom endpoints in baucis.

```
 var controller = baucis.rest('User');
 controller.swagger.apis.push({
   'path': '/users/login',
   'description': 'Logs a user in',
   'operations': [
     {
       'httpMethod': 'POST',
       'nickname': 'Login',
       'responseClass': 'User',
       'summary': 'Requests auth token given username and password'
     }]})
```

However, in this case above, I'd like to set the response class to {token : string} instead of 'User', and set parameters to {username: string, password: string}, so that the 'Try it out!' button works.

Any ideas how I would go about this? Or if it is possible in baucis-swagger?

Answer (score 2):

Seems the baucis object above just follows the [swagger specification](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject).

Adding a parameters definitions object array, and a responses definition object array to the object above solves my problem.